# A View doesn’t receive @AppStorage updates when passed as a parameter into another View

Tags: swiftui

I have a View that accepts another View as a parameter:

```swift
struct ListItem<Content: View>: View {
  
  let title: String
  let suffix: () -> Content   // 1. Receive a View
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text(title)
      Spacer()
      suffix()                // 2. Render the View
    }
  }
}
```

Then I pass a View with dynamic `@AppStorage` content into it:

```swift
struct MyList: View {
  
  @AppStorage("counter") var counter: Int = 0   // 3. Define a UserDefaults value
  
  var body: some View {
    ListItem(title: "Counter") {
      Text("\(counter)")                        // 4. Pass the UserDefaults value
    }
    Button("Increment") {
      counter += 1                              // 5. Change the UserDefaults value
    }
  }
}
```

When I tap the button, the rendered value isn’t updated:

[Tapping_Increment_With_No_Visible_Results.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFDSS.gif)

This problem doesn’t exists when using a `@State` or an `@Environment` value.

Only when the View updates, eg. one of its children causes a re-render or `onAppear` is fired, the new value is shown.

#### Question

Is this the expected behavior of `@AppStorage` or a bug? Are there other cases when passing a View as a parameter may cause its state to become stale?

#### Workaround

I tried creating a ViewModifier instead:

```swift
struct ListItemizer: ViewModifier {
  
  let title: String
  
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    HStack {
      Text(title)
      Spacer()
      content                                 // 1. Render a View
    }
  }
}
```

Then applying the modifier to the View with dynamic content:

```swift
struct MyList: View {
  
  @AppStorage("counter") var counter: Int = 0
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("\(counter)")
      .modifier(
        ListItemizer(title: "Counter")         // 2. Apply a modifier to a View
      )                                        //    with dynamic content
    Button("Increment") {
      counter += 1
    }
  }
}
```

When I tap on the button, the rendered value is updated immediately, as expected:

[Tapping_Incerement_With_Visible_Results.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TysrI.gif)

Answer (score 0):

suffix() needs to be inside init  eg

```
init(suffix: () -> Content) {
    content = suffix()
}
```